# Problem with defining text.latex.preamble in mplstyle

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I need to use LateX `\geqslant` in matplotlib, so I need to include `amssymb` in the LateX preamble.
When I try to do it on mplstyle file (my preferred way) with `text.latex.preamble: [r'\usepackage{amssymb}']`, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 252, in _run_checked_subprocess
    report = subprocess.check_output(
  File "/Users/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/Users/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['latex', '-interaction=nonstopmode', '--halt-on-error', '/Users/machine/.matplotlib/tex.cache/d98102e4e0cad95eda43d99a7618cd63.tex']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 45, in _draw
    self.figure.draw(renderer)
  File "/Users/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 74, in draw_wrapper
    result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 51, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 2790, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  File "/Users/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 132, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/Users/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 51, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/deprecation.py", line 431, in wrapper
    return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
  File "/Users/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2881, in draw
    self._update_title_position(renderer)
  File "/Users/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2822, in _update_title_position
    if title.get_window_extent(renderer).ymin < top:
  File "/Users/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 903, in get_window_extent
    bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
  File "/Users/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 306, in _get_layout
    _, lp_h, lp_d = renderer.get_text_width_height_descent(
  File "/Users/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 229, in get_text_width_height_descent
    w, h, d = texmanager.get_text_width_height_descent(
  File "/Users/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 399, in get_text_width_height_descent
    dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
  File "/Users/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 291, in make_dvi
    self._run_checked_subprocess(
  File "/Users/machine/miniforge3/envs/py39deps26-source/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 260, in _run_checked_subprocess
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string:
b'lp'

Here is the full report generated by latex:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2022/dev) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/Users/machine/.matplotlib/tex.cache/d98102e4e0cad95eda43d99a7618cd63.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/type1cm/type1cm.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/mathpazo.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cm-super/type1ec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmr.fd))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
! Argument of \@fileswith@ptions has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.11 ...package{amsmath}',r'\usepackage{siunitx}']
                                                  
No pages of output.
Transcript written on d98102e4e0cad95eda43d99a7618cd63.log.
```

Any idea why?

Update: I found that if I don't define LateX preamble in mplstyle but rather include the same line (`rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{amssymb}']`)in py code, this works. In any case, if anyone can help, I'd like to know how can I define this in the .mplstyle file.

Here is a dummy code to reproduce this:

```
value=2.5
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
ax.set_title(f'$\\geqslant {value}$')
```

I'm in MacOs with TexLive freshly updated.

Comment: Try to remove the r and the [ ]=> `text.latex.preamble : \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{amssymb}`

Comment: it doesn't work. I get exactly the same error for both excluding the r and/or the []